# disable browsers back button but keep it enable within my asp.net application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, back-button

I have searched and implemented a code where I am able to disable the back button of the browser. But I am facing a problem like when I log in and don't do anything and click back button it takes me to login page and then a forward button appears. I don't want the back button to get functional on my home screen immediately when I am logged in. But the back button should be enable within my application but not exactly after i log in. Following is my code that I have used in my master page coding. Please help as I am working on live application.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function disableBackButton() {
            window.history.forward(1);
            //alert("You cannot Nevigate To Back!!!");
        }

</script>

<body onload="disableBackButton()" >
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

On code behind(Server side) write this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();


   }
```

and on client side write  this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.history.forward(1);
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", my_onkeydown_handler);
function my_onkeydown_handler()
{
switch (event.keyCode)
{
case 116 : // F5;
event.returnValue = false;
event.keyCode = 0;
window.status = "We have disabled F5";
break;
}
}
</script>
```

Lot's of way's [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/252142/How-to-disable-browsers-back-button.aspx#answer1)

Comment: Should I add this in master page itself or on every page

Comment: Yes , if you need to disable all page back button , you sould be add in master page otherwise you can add each page !!!!

Comment: Will this suffice my problem of disabling back button just after login and enabling it through out the application.?